# How to use XSLT to generate one ouput xml file by reading & processing from multiple input xml

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0, xsl-fo, xslt-grouping

Friends,

I am new to XSLT. Please help to get the below logic. I am using unix machine

From the below 3 input xml file, need to add 'count' field value by using xslt and need to generate output with added value in count field

```
Input XML 1

<topic>
<topicName>Billing</topicName>
<property>
<make>HONDA</make>
<Model>ACCORD</Model>
</property>
<count>10</count>
</topic>
<topic>
<topicName>Billing</topicName>
<property>
<make>TOYOTO</make>
<Model>CAMRY</Model>
</property>
<count>20</count>
</topic>
<topic>
<topicName>Billing</topicName>
<property>
<make>NISSAN</make>
<Model>ALTIMA</Model>
</property>
<count>30</count>
</topic>
```

Input XML 2

```
<topic>
<topicName>Billing</topicName>
<property>
<make>HONDA</make>
<Model>ACCORD</Model>
</property>
<count>100</count>
</topic>
<topic>
<topicName>Billing</topicName>
<property>
<make>TOYOTO</make>
<Model>CAMRY</Model>
</property>
<count>200</count>
</topic>
<topic>
<topicName>Billing</topicName>
<property>
<make>NISSAN</make>
<Model>ALTIMA</Model>
</property>
<count>300</count>
</topic>
```

Input XML 3

```
<topic>
<topicName>Billing</topicName>
<property>
<make>HONDA</make>
<Model>ACCORD</Model>
</property>
<count>1000</count>
</topic>
<topic>
<topicName>Billing</topicName>
<property>
<make>TOYOTO</make>
<Model>CAMRY</Model>
</property>
<count>2000</count>
</topic>
<topic>
<topicName>Billing</topicName>
<property>
<make>NISSAN</make>
<Model>ALTIMA</Model>
</property>
<count>3000</count>
</topic>
```

From the above 3 input xml file, need to add count value by using xslt and need to generate output with added value for count field

OUTPUT XML:

```
<topic>
<topicName>Billing</topicName>
<property>
<make>HONDA</make>
<Model>ACCORD</Model>
</property>
<count>1110</count>
</topic>
<topic>
<topicName>Billing</topicName>
<property>
<make>TOYOTO</make>
<Model>CAMRY</Model>
</property>
<count>2220</count>
</topic>
<topic>
<topicName>Billing</topicName>
<property>
<make>NISSAN</make>
<Model>ALTIMA</Model>
</property>
<count>3330</count>
</topic>
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: How do you identify `topic`s in the different files to be grouped together, by `make` and `Model`?

Answer (score 1):

Read up on the `document()` function, and (for 1.1) the `doc()` function.

In 1.1, read up on `xsl:for-each-group` and `deep-equal()`.

In both 1.0 and 1.1, read up on `sum()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can read in files using collection (the syntax used in the sample is Saxon 9 specific):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:param name="file-pattern" select="'topic*.xml'"/>

    <xsl:template name="main">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="collection(concat('.?select=', $file-pattern))//topic" group-by="concat(property/make, '|', property/Model)">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:copy-of select="topicName, property"/>
                <count>
                    <xsl:value-of select="sum(current-group()/count)"/>
                </count>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Run Saxon 9 using `-it:main` to start with that template called `main`.

Comment: Thanks for your input.  While executing xslt, got this error .... "javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unsupported XSL element 'http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform:for-each-group' "

Comment: You need need to download and use Saxon 9 to be able to use XSLT 2.0.

Comment: Saxon 9 is available in an open source version from http://saxon.sourceforge.net/#F9.7HE.

Comment: Thanks for your information.
Currently I am not able to install new tool in development unix machine because of Management policy in my concern.

So please guide me how to achieve this (reading data from multiple input) in other way.

Comment: Well, the question is tagged as XSLT 2.0 so you should have access to XSLT 2.0. As for reading multiple files in XSLT 1.0, see the other answer with the hint to the document function https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#document. Grouping with multiple files in XSLT 1.0 is more difficult, as the usual Muenchian grouping approach using a key is specific to grouping nodes from one document. So you might need to create a result tree fragment first which merges the nodes from the different documents, then group the result tree fragment converted to a node-set with `exsl:node-set`.